# Create a stub version of a C++ class

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I'd like to create a stub or mock version of a class based on a preprocessor define.  When the preprocessor macro is set to "enable", the class is just a normal class.  When set to "disable", the class is an empty stub that the compiler can hopefully optimize entirely away.  Yet code that compiles or does not compile cleanly with the real class should have the corresponding behavior with the stub class as well.

Here's an example of what this might look like:

```
class _foo {
 public:
    foo(int x) : x_(x) {}
    void add(int x) { x_ += x; }
    void add(const char *str) { x_ += atoi(str); }
    bool isset(void) { return x_ > 0; }
 private:
    int x_;
};

#if ENABLE_FOO
using foo = _foo;
#else
class foo {
 public:
    foo(int x) {}   
    void add(int x) { return; }
    void add(const char *str) { return; }
    bool isset(void) { return false; }
};
#endif
```

The definition of `isset()` is intended to allow code like `if (a_foo.isset()) { code(); }` to be optimized away to nothing.  Obviously this can't work universally for any method and any use of that method.  One would need to design the class so that 0, false, NULL, etc. were sensible return values in the disabled case.

This works fine, but one must keep the stub version of `foo` perfectly in sync with the real version.  Every change to any method must be duplicated in the stub.  This is annoying.  How to make the stub more automatic?  Ideally one could write `class foo_stub : public stub<foo> {};` or `STUB(foo)` and the stub class is created from that alone.

To this end, I've been able to come up with this so far:

```
class foo {
 public:
    CTOR_STUB(_foo, foo);
    METHOD_STUB(_foo, add);
    METHOD_STUB(_foo, isset);
};
```

That creates the stub version of `_foo`.  One does need to list each method name, but neither the return type, nor the arguments, nor the number of arguments need be provided.  All overloads (i.e., both `add()` methods) are covered by one `METHOD_STUB`.  The overloads can have different return types.  It even works if stubbed method is a method template.

Here are the macros that do this:

```
#define METHOD_STUB(base, func) \
    template <typename... Args> \
    auto func(Args... args) { \
        using RetType = decltype(std::declval<base>().func(std::forward<Args>(args)...)); \
        return (RetType)0; }

#define CTOR_STUB(base, name) \
    template <typename... Args> \
    name(Args... args) { return; base _dummy{std::forward<Args>(args)...}; }
```

The idea is to define a template that requires that a method with the appropriate arguments and return type exists in the stubbed class in order to compile correctly, yet will be optimized to nothing by the compiler.

Is there a way to avoid macros, and do this using only templates?  It seems like one would want the name of the method to be a template parameter and I don't see how to do that.

Is there a way to avoid needing to provide the name of the current class in `CTOR_STUB()`?  The compiler does know the name, but I can't see a way to get the name as a symbol that can be used to define the constructor template, vs getting the class name as a text string or a type.

Is there some flaw that would allow the stub to compile correctly or fail to compile when the real version of the class would not do the same?

Comment: Propagating the change in the signature is not any different than propagating a change in a typical class (i.e. non-template) that has separate definitions and declarations. If you forget to do it you'll get compile time errors. I don't see the benefits here as outweighing having to use macros.

Comment: `(RetType)0` can be dangerous. You probably mean `static_cast<RetType>(0)`.

Comment: @NirFriedman, a difference, besides there being yet one more place to update when a signature changes, is the conditional compilation.  If one forgets to update the stub and builds in the "enabled" case there is no error as the stub isn't used.  And if one fails to update a user of the class, there is no error in a "disabled" case.  Linking them automatically ensures one gets the same compile time checking in both enabled and disabled cases.

Comment: @TrentP Well, there are a variety of approaches one can take, that may have small amounts of duplication, IMHO all still better than macros. The key point though is that the stub and the true class must both be defined in both builds. Using a macro for conditional compilation like this is a bad idea. The macro can be used to define a constexpr bool which can be fed into `std::conditional` to select the class being used.

Answer (score 1):

Not a perfect solution but you could do

```
#ifdef ENABLE
#define IF_ENABLED(x) x
#define IF_DISABLED(x)
#else
#define IF_ENABLED(x)
#define IF_DISABLED(x) x
#endif

class Foo {
public:
    foo(int x) IF_ENABLED(: x_(x)) {}
    void add(int x) { IF_ENABLED(x_ += x;) }
    void add(const char *str) { IF_ENABLED(x_ += atoi(str);) }
    bool isset(void) { IF_ENABLED(return x_ > 0;) IF_DISABLED(return false;) }
private:
#ifdef ENABLE
    int x_;
#endif
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A good solution that completely avoids macros (other than what enters from the build system) is as follows:

```
#if ENABLE_FOO
constexpr bool g_use_foo = true;
#else
constexpr bool g_use_foo = false;
#endif

template <bool FooEnabled>
struct Foo {
  void bar1() {}
};

template <>
void Foo<true>::bar1() { std::cerr << "not a mock\n"; }

using UserFoo = Foo<g_use_foo>;
```

Live example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ecdb7c1a7f0a6068

Basically, we declare a template class, and give the generic trivial mock implementation inline. Out of body we define a specialization for the class with the actual functionality. It's worth nothing that the declarations inline and out of line have to match exactly, otherwise you are specializing something that hasn't been declared. So you get a compile time error if you update one but not the other. Note that this pretty well mirrors a typical non-template class where you have declarations inline and definitions out so I think it's pretty reasonable.

The only case this doesn't cover is if you remove, or forget to implement, a method on the real object. This will still compile, you'll just get the mock functionality even if you think you are using the real object. That said, I don't see this as a major concern. Even the most basic one line unit test would fail in that case. If you are worried about this, you can just write:

```
template <bool FooEnabled>
struct Foo {
  void bar1() { static_assert(!FooEnabled, "");}
};
```

Which will catch this.

You can cover state as well pretty easily. Just privately inherit from a struct with state:

```
template <bool FooEnabled>
struct Foo : private std::conditional_t<FooEnabled, FooState, EmptyStruct> {
    void bar1() {}
};
```

Note that both classes are fully defined and usable regardless of the build, this has considerable benefits for testing and tooling.